# Is there a translator tool for translating EBNF to boost::spirit?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

The translator could be in boost::spirit too.
I couldn't find any in the Internet.
Maybe I should make one?

Answer (score 1):

From the [spirit introduction](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/distrib/spirit_1_8_5/libs/spirit/doc/introduction.html):

> Expression templates allow us to approximate the syntax of Extended Backus-Normal Form (EBNF) completely in C++.

So you can *almost* write plain EBNF, no need for a *translator*.

I'm not so familiar with spirit to know how exactly the syntax is different, but if the differences of *spirit C++ EBNF* and *real EBNF* are minor a simple [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) script may suffice.
If not you are right, you could write a spirit parser that understands EBNF and then use the AST to create C++ code that is a spirit representation of that AST.

Comment: For large EBNFs (http://grammatica.percederberg.net/grammar/asn1/asn1.grammar), even thou it's almost identical, it's still a pain. It's not necessary to have one, but it would be helpful.

Comment: If your Grammar is that large, you probably don't want to use Spirit for it ;)

Comment: @Diego: Couple of things here -- Spirit has been almost completely rewritten since I posted this answer -- now the correct tool to use would be `boost::spirit::qi` and it's a lot better. But my biggest older complaints with Spirit are still there. 1. If your grammar has a syntax error, lord help the poor soul who has to decipher the template error messages it generates. 2. Compile times are extremely long even for relatively simple grammars.